# Access denied for user 'www-data@'localhost

Tags: php

I'm trying to configure a my ubuntu 14.04 server to run my web application that I created awhile ago. It was on a different server than and now I'm migrating it.

So I've put everything in the var/www/html folder

Ran the following in Putty 
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Once I go to my actual website I get the following error message

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

If I go directly to the .htaccess redirect file I can get to the first page fine, its when I try to do anything with the database it seems to fail.

The user I created has enough access to login or register a new user on the site etc, but this error is stopping me.

Comment: The error is an SQL error, nothing to do with .htaccess

Comment: As paullb indicates, your post lacks a lot of the information we need to help you. Which SQL platform are you using? Did you migrate the database along with the web application files? It appears that in your application, you are telling it to connect to the SQL server with the user account 'www-data' and no password, did you create that user when migrating the data? It really does appear to be an authentication problem, nothing more.

Comment: Hi I actually found my issue in the actual website itself. in the config.php i didn't put the SQL user credentials. But everywhere else I did so I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify config.php as it was missing mysql user credentials, hence why it was searching in the www-data group which had no password.

Answer (score 1):

This is an SQL issue. Nothing to do with your .htaccess.

Use "show grants" on my SQL server (assuming it's mysql) to see what users have access to what.

Here are some examples of possible issues:

Your error indicates you didn't pass a password.

- Does this user require a password to access sql?
- Does the user www-data exist?
- Does the user www-data have the ability to access from localhost.